# How to Group a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I group the array based Name Menu Category and Name Menu ? Is there any native php functions are available to do this? I 've searched on google but not yet well understood

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Products'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'A',
        'url' => 'a'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => 'A1',
        'url' => 'a1'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Products'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'A',
        'url' => 'a'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => 'A2',
        'url' => 'a2'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Products'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'B',
        'url' => 'b'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
(int) 3 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Data'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'A',
        'url' => 'a'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
(int) 4 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Data'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'B',
        'url' => 'b'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => 'B1',
        'url' => 'b1'
    )
),
(int) 5 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Data'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'C',
        'url' => 'c'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
(int) 6 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Report'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'A',
        'url' => 'a'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
(int) 7 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Report'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'B',
        'url' => 'b'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
(int) 8 => array(
    'MenuCategory' => array(
        'name' => 'Report'
    ),
    'Menu' => array(
        'name' => 'C',
        'url' => 'c'
    ),
    'Sub' => array(
        'name' => null,
        'url' => null
    )
),
```

This is a result that will be issued later

- Products

  - [A](http://example)

    - [A1](http://example)
    - [A2](http://example)
  - [B](http://example)
- Data

  - [A](http://example)
  - [B](http://example)

    - [B1](http://example)
  - [C](http://example)
- Report

  - [A](http://example)
  - [B](http://example)
  - [C](http://example)

Comment: Do you want to order your array based on the values of MenuCategory['name'] and Menu['name'] ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I assume your array variable name is `$menu`, try this code.

```
$new = array();
array_map(function($a) use(&$new){
    if($a['Sub']['name'])
        $new[$a['MenuCategory']['name']][$a['Menu']['name']][$a['Sub']['name']] = $a['Sub']['name'];
    else 
        $new[$a['MenuCategory']['name']][$a['Menu']['name']] = $a['Menu']['name'];
}, $menu);
print_r($new);
```

and will output

```
Array
(
    [Products] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [A1] => A1
                    [A2] => A2
                )

            [B] => B
        )

    [Data] => Array
        (
            [A] => A
            [B] => Array
                (
                    [B1] => B1
                )

            [C] => C
        )

    [Report] => Array
        (
            [A] => A
            [B] => B
            [C] => C
        )

)
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Group them by level first

use foreach to sort them example

```
foreach ($input_arr as $key => &$entry) {
    $level_arr[$entry['level']][$key] = $entry;
}
```